# How to find number of native threads available in mediaserver in android?

Tags: android

Is there any command to know what are the threads available in particular process like mediaserver process.

Answer (score 0):

U can use DDMS from eclipse, There you enable `Thread Update` for android.process.media thats it. It shows all threads running on device for that process.

Comment: Hey Charan,You are right.But I want to get all native threads also.